# Ninject - Binding.GetProvider throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm using version 2.2.0.0 of Ninject in a asp.net web forms application and after a few hundred requests, it sometimes throws a NullReferenceException in the GetProvider method of the Binding class.

Example stack trace: http://pastebin.com/BbhsPQMT

The exception only occurs when I stress test the application and the origin of the exception is usually different (resolving distinct interfaces).

In order to try to understand why this issue was ocurring I looked at the Ninject source code and inserted some lines of code for debugging purposes. I later confirmed that the object that is null is the ProviderCallback property in the Binding class.

I also put some code in the set operator of the ProviderCallback property in order to understand if it was being set to null. After running some tests and looking at some memory dumps it seems that the ProviderCallback property is not being set to a null value and so I think the instance being collected by GC.

I still do not understand why this is happening...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** We upgraded to the latest version of Ninject just to check if the exception still occurs but we got the same exception after stress testing the application: http://pastebin.com/YaiaZndz

Comment: You should report this. A NullReferenceException always indicates a bug in the code that throws it.

Comment: Try to update to the latest Ninject version.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you the reason for this issue as I can't reproduce such a behavior. But here are some steps you can take to identify the problem.

As you say the issue is caused by a `ProviderCallback` that is `null`. This can't be caused by GC because GC will never assign `null` to a property. Instead you will get an already disposed exception or other strange behaviors. But there are some other reasons how this can happen:

1. `Null` is assigned at some time, but since you verified this already this is not the reason.
2. It was never assigned at all.
3. A new `BindingConfiguration` is created at a later time.

The 3rd point can easily be verified by adding a breakpoint in the `BindingConfiguration` constructor. It shouldn't be called anymore after the kernel is succesfully configured and you start resolving objects.

For the second problem execute the following after the kernel configuration:

```
var kernel = your fully configured kernel;
var bindingsField = typeof(KernelBase).GetField("bindings", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var bindings = bindingsField.GetValue(kernel) as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Type, ICollection<IBinding>>>;

foreach (var bindingsEntry in bindings
    .Where(bindingsEntry => bindingsEntry.Value
        .Any(binding => binding.BindingConfiguration.ProviderCallback == null)))
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("No Provider callback defined for {0}.", bindingsEntry.Key));
}
```

Comment: Hi Remo. Sorry for the late reply but I was trying to see whether any of the conditions you provided were true. Neither the 2nd or the 3rd ever happened. This is proving very hard to reproduce because only happens every hundred requests to the aspx page. One weird thing I saw, was a second StandardKernel in a memory dump but I could not figure out where it was being created (!refs and !gcroot returned only a root to a huge array of objects that seems to be a static member of the appdomain - I still do not understand why).

Comment: Can't you find out where it is created by adding a breakpoint in the constructor of the Kernel?

Comment: Remo, I found why it is created. In version 3 of Ninject there is now a dependency for the Ninject.Web namespace which is creating a StandardKernel impliclity in the Ninject.Web.KernelContainer. I am now back to my original issue. I have no idea where to look next. Let me just tell you just we are also getting some rare ActivationExceptions that once start happening they continue to be thrown until we restart the application pool. I think this issues might be related. This is happening in version 2.2 and I was able to also get rare ActivationExceptions in version 3 (after hundreds of requests)

Comment: So the current state is:

1. No ProviderCallback is null initially.
2. No new BindingConfiguration is created later.
3. Nothing is assigned to ProviderCallback later.
4. Just one Kernel is used. 

In that case I don't see how this could happen. Can you create a stripped down solution to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Yes. That is the current state. I tried to create another solution just to reproduce this issue but I didn't get this exception. Right now I am trying to correlate this issue with some ActivationExceptions by adding some instrumentation code and looking at memory dumps. Maybe they are related...

Comment: Remo, I think we found the underlying problem. We are seeing two keys added to the Multimap _items dictionary (used for the bindingCache in KernelBase). It seems to be caused by a race condition. Any ideas?

Comment: There was an issue with Ninject 2.2 which is solved in the meantime. If you are testing with 3.0 the only way I can think of this could happen is if you are adding bindings during runtime. But this isn't recommended anyway because it will give you an unpredictable outcome.

Comment: The ActivationException is being thrown because Rebind is not thread-safe as it uses indirectly the Bindings property of the KernelBase. This property is a Multimap which is not thread-safe because it does not implement a lock in the this[Key] getter which manages the private dictionary. This issue also exists in Ninject 3.

Comment: @TiagoMargalho Thanks for the investigation. I strongly suggest not to do any bind or rebind after the first resolve of an object because the result is unpredictable even if the multi threading issue is solved. E.g. you can still get instances of the previous implementation if there are objects with other scopes than transient. Try to use the RRR - Pattern: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx